# Start my program at login in MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, startup, login-script

I am developing a program in C++ in MacOSX, and I want to add an option to start my program at login. I investigated some possible solutions in MacOSX, but I did not understand well which is the best/the official suggested one nowadays. Some of them are easy, some more complicated, and it seems that the easier ones are not the suggested ones for the future.

Here a resume of what I found:

- using [OsaScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310495/can-login-items-be-added-via-the-command-line-in-high-sierra): it seems the simplest one, but I really would like a C/C++ API, and not using the osascript command
- From the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html), I can see the 'Service Management framework', but I want the user be able to see my app started at login in the preference, and I would not like to create another helper bundle...
- Again from the official documentation, I can see [Launch Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services), but I am not sure it is what I need. I did not find any example in C/C++, and if I search for the 'Login' keyword, I just see two deprecated functions therein...
- [Technical Note TN2228](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2228/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007991) it seems a complete guide and with also some example therein, but it speaks about creating a 'authorization plug-in'. Do I really need that to start my app at login?
- [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) it seems the preferred way to launch a Daemon, but my app is not really a daemon...

So, what do you suggest me to do?

Do you know some other way to make my programm running at login?

Which one do you think is the easiest but not deprecated solution?

Do you have some example in C/C++? All the example I found are in other languages...

Thanks everybody

PS:

At the end I chose the OsaScript solution (one line of code...)
From [this example](https://gist.github.com/kaloprominat/6111584) you can see that you can set the property "name" when you add your item so that you can delete it later.

I am still looking for a easy C++ solution...

Comment: Just drag it to your *"Login items"* https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25590?locale=en_GB

Comment: That is what the user can do, but I am the developer of the app :) . I want to do the same but programmatically, so that I can have a checkbox or something in my app "Start me at login"

Comment: If it's not a daemon, then you should let your users opt-in in the way Mark describes.

Comment: What do you mean, that all the solutions I found are deprecated if my app is not a daemon? Only daemons will be allowed in the future to be started on login?